# Seam 2.2.2.Final new operator in EJBQL

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, seam, seam2

i am having a problem with EntityQuery from Seam 2.2.2.Final, I can´t use the "new" operator in EJBQL,

"Select new com.ej.Prest(prest.id, prest.name) from Prest prest"

anyone has resolved this?

Answer (score 2):

If `com.ej.Prest` is a JPA entity, you don't need to use `new`, just query it:

```
select p from Prest p
```

or even:

```
from Prest
```

If it is not a JPA entity, then you cannot use it in the `from` clause, you need to use only JPA entities there. You can for example do (in this example, `MyEntity` is a JPA entity with `name` and `surname` properties used in the constructor for `Prest`:

```
select new com.ej.Prest(me.name, me.surname) from MyEntity me
```

Also, you need to define the constructor with the right arguments, in this case in `com.ej.Prest`:

```
public Prest(String name, String surname) {
  // constructor code here
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do that, just override `getCountEjbql()` and return the query you want (`select count(*) from Prest prest` in your case).